# Action after timeout in FreeSwitch

Tags: voip, freeswitch, ivr

By default, when we create a new `IVR` in `FreeSwitch` and the timeout expires, the call is closed. But i want to redirect the caller to a specific extension. Which `XML` file has this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after you call the application `ivr` in your dialplan, the next application after it would be executed on timeout. It's also executed if IVR has finished correctly. So what I usually do is that the IVR always uses `transfer` on valid input. Then the next application after `ivr` is guaranteed to be called only on failure.

Comment: @Stanislav, Can you elaborate! I want similar thing. You mean here, to introduce some TRANSFER function in dialplan. I too want to have NO TIMEOUT effect, as I answer channel directly.

Comment: @bhavesh369 I don't quite understand what you want

Comment: I mean, can you elaborate your answer! What is this "transfer on valid input" thing.

Comment: you build an IVR where "transfer" application is called on user input. You just need to read the FreeSWITCH documentation or buy consulting :)